# Translation Golf XXXI - I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Bienvenidos de nuevo al [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf). No tenía mucha idea de qué texto poner en esta ocasión, así que me fui a Google, busqué "most famous quotes", abrí [el primer enlace](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes) y escogí una que me pareció corta (153 caracteres) pero golfeable a la par. Es la siguiente:

> "I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best."
>
> ― Marilyn Monroe

Una posible traducción de 151 caracteres sería:

> Soy egoísta, impaciente y algo insegura. Cometo errores, me descontrolo y a veces soy insoportable. Pero si no me soportas en mi peor momento, entonces seguro que no me mereces en el mejor.

Como siempre, la traducción que respete el original usando el menor número de caracteres, gana.

Enlaces:

- [Normas del juego](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637).
- [Contador de caracteres](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/).
- [Chat oficial del stack](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), donde podrás conocer a otros participantes.

Comment: Que sepáis que ahora, una hora más tarde, por fin he logrado darme cuenta de por qué estaba mal lo de "yo no te merezco". :-D Madre mía la vejez...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### <s>78 49 41</s> 37

> Erro, dudo, no paro. Yo, yo, yo. ¿Mucho? No mereces más.

Comment: ¿La rima la has puesto a propósito? :-D

Comment: ¡Eres el ganador! Ha sido un buen combate, blonfu te lo ha puesto difícil...

Answer (score 5):

#### <s>115 88  55 48</s> 40 caracteres

> Toma mi ego, prisa, duda, yerros y manías o pasa de mí.

Comment: @walen pensaba que solo se podía decir *yerro* pero hoy he descubierto que *erro* es correcto también.

Comment: Gracias por corregirme *olvidaté*, se me ha ido la olla porque he repasado la palabra dos veces y he pensado que estaba bien.

Comment: Muy bueno el edit, logras poner el mensaje original en tan pocas palabras.

Answer (score 4):

#### 71

> Soy egoísta, ansiosa e insegura. Impulsiva e incontrolable, ¿de malas no?
>   menos de buenas.

Comment: Esta traducción está ya un poco demasiado ofuscada para mi gusto, vas a tener que defenderla. ¿Cómo se sabe que Marylin está hablando de sí misma?

Comment: @Charlie jaja, y, ¿si agrego -Marilyn Monroe al final cuenta? o simplemente podría agregar "Soy" al principio...

Comment: Agregar "soy" es justo la opción que yo contemplaba. :-)

Answer (score 4):

#### 61

> Soy egoista, loca, cerril, apurada. La cago. ¿así me niegas? No mereces mi gloria.